# Loading another view from table selection without losing navigation (back)

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have an app that is controled through a UITabBar. In one of the sections within the tab bar, I have a navigation table. It works fine from an example I did from one of the books but I want to be able to go another view controller (aka another xib file) when the user selects a row and I want the user to be able to go back easily. I realize this has to do with pushingViewControllers but I am stuck. Here is where I think the problem is. my code is at the bottom. If you notice, I commented out

```
       // [self presentModalViewController:flowerDetailViewController animated:YES];
```

While this did take me to the my flowerDetailViewController XIB file, I lost the ability to do navigation (go back). If anyone has any ideas or suggestions, it would be much appreciated.

Thank you

```
     -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
     didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

FlowerDetailViewController *flowerDetailViewController = 
[[FlowerDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:
 @"FlowerDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
/*flowerDetailViewController.detailURL=
[[NSURL alloc] initWithString: 
 [[[flowerData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex: 
   indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"url"]];*/
flowerDetailViewController.title=
[[[flowerData objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex: 
  indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
//[self presentModalViewController:flowerDetailViewController animated:YES];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:
 flowerDetailViewController animated:YES];
[flowerDetailViewController release];
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make any sense to execute these two methods **on the same view consecutively.**

```
[self presentModalViewController:flowerDetailViewController animated:YES];
```

..

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController: flowerDetailViewController animated:YES];
```

because they give  a very different result, from user experience point of view.

**The first one** presents a view **modaly.** Modaly means, that he application brings up the view to the top (imagine a Z-axis, when you hold the phone, it is a line from the phone to you, on top of it means closer to you), and the user is stuck in that view exclusively because it is on the top, he/she cannot touch anything else from the application unless he resolves the options presented in the view and the view goes away.

**The second** method  is **pushing the view onto he stack of views** that all belong to the navigation controller. The navigation controller pushes views onto the screen like you would lay a stack of cards onto the table, card1, put onto that card 2, put onto that card 3...and so on card N. But you still have the ability to touch other options that are all around the navigation controller.To get back to the card 1, you need to remove card(views) that are on top of it, for removing on-top views, the navigation controller provides the back button automatically.

Only you cann tell, which of these two is handy in terms of your application UI and design.